# Prove that $XX^\top$ and $X^\top X$ have the same eigenvalues

Tags: self-study, pca, eigenvalues

I'm not sure how to do the following exercise. Could someone help me by either suggesting the knowledge I should have to solve this, or pointing me out in the right direction?

I have tried to expand B and A by substituting X in the equations, and then trying to get the eigenvalues for each. But, for B, I got a 1x1 reduction, while for A, it's a N by N.

When I tried to calculate the eigenvalues, A presented the greatest problem and that's where I got stuck.

But I think that I'm taking the difficult approach and the proof should be simpler.

[image: exercise 3]

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will be surprised by how simple the problem is if you approach it from the right angle. Start from the definitions of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. It only takes a few manipulations afterwards to get where you want. Both problems can be solved almost on the spot.

To illustrate, for the matrix $\mathbf{A}^{\prime}\mathbf{A}$ we have by definition

$$\mathbf{A}^{\prime} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{x} $$

Multiply both sides by $\mathbf{A}$ to get

$$\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{\prime} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$$

but then we see that $\lambda$ is still an eigenvalue for $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{\prime}$ and the corresponding eigenvector is simply  $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$. Your intuition was correct.

From this you can also get the relationship between the eigenvectors. Note that while we have equal eigenvalues, it would be unreasonable to expect equal eigenvectors as well. You can see the comment section below for a relevant discussion.

You can do the other case on your own.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, approaching from the right angle. Just to be sure, I left multiply by X the definition of eigenvalues, then A turned into B. And given that lambda was the same for both. The conclusion is that they share the same eigenvalues. Is that correct? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @hugo See my updated answer.

Comment: @JohnK wrote "Interestingly, there is a theorem in linear algebra that says that the eigenvectors are the same if and only if the matrices commute".   This is false in both directions, Strang's book notwithstanding. 'Same eignevectors -> matrices commute' requires diagonlizability.  'Matrices commute implies same eigenvectors' requires distinct eigenvalues of both matrices.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Yes, this comes from Strang's book indeed. He also offers a proof.

Comment: @JohnK An incorrect and/or incomplete proof, although I have not seen the latest edition of his book. Do you see a proof there which does not implicitly make the additional assumptions I mentioned? It's not just a question of  a more difficult proof; without those assumptions the claims are false.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone In his latest edition, he adds that the matrices have to be diagonalizable for this to hold. You are correct. He also says, however, that there is a longer proof for the case of repeating eigenvalues although it is substatially longer and he does not offer it.

Comment: @JohnK, that addresses one direction. Does he mention that distinct eigenvalues are required in the other direction?  E.g., consider a multiple of the identity matrix (which is diagonalizable!!) as one of the matrices, it commutes with any other compatibly dimensioned matrix, regardless of its eignevectors.

Comment: @JohnK, your edited version "Interestingly, there is a theorem in linear algebra that says that the eigenvectors of diagonalizable matrices are the same if and only if the matrices commute" is still wrong in one direction per my immediately preceding comment, although I see your edit was made just before I posted that comment.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I also edited my comment above. Strang is aware of the problem you mentioned and says that a proof exists for repeated eigenvalues, without him giving it because he claims it is long.

Comment: Let A = [1 0;0 1]. B = [1 2;3 4] in MATLAB notation. Then A and B commute and are both diagonalizable, but do not share the same eigenvectors. A, of course, has repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I'll remove the comment because this is a good point and it looks like Strang has got it wrong, or at least half-right anwyay. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.